# Rerouting URL path to parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I want to mask the URL `http://example.com/index.php?path=controller/function` to `http://example.com/controller/function`. `function` isn't required to be present.

How can I do this with an htaccess file?

The following isn't working.

```
RewriteRule ^/?assets/(.*)$ assets/$1 [L] # directory for CSS, images, and JavaScript
RewriteRule ^$ /index [redirect]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?([a-zA-Z/]*)$ index.php?path=$1/$2 [L]
```

Currently, if I enter `http://example.com/controller/function` in the browser, I receive a 404 error, but entering `http://example.com/index.php?path=controller/function` works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(.*)?$ index.php?path=$1$2   [L]
```

It maps internally

`http://example.com/var1/var2`

To:

`http://example.com/index.php?path=var1/var2`

Keeps the incoming trailing slash behavior and `var2` is optional.

Comment: what if you need to rewrite `http://example.com/uploads/var1/var2/file.txt` to `http://example.com/index.php?filepath=var1/var2/file.txt`?